Can the zipfile library in Python be used to show file paths for files in a zipfile?
Can the zipfile library in Python be used to show file paths for files in a zipfile?
I am able to use .namelist() to generate the names for each file, however is there a similar function I can call to show the file paths of all files in a currently zipped file?

The name inculdes the path, doesn't it?

No, the name only prints the name of the file within the zip folder. Not the file path.

When I use ZipFile.namelist() it returns whatever path in available in the ZipFile entry, which can be a full path, a relative path, or just the filename alone.

Are you sure the zip file even includes file paths?  Many don't, particularly the ones generated by Windows as zip folders.

Unfortunately I this command displays is the file name, in this case a JSON file.

Exactly what "path" do you expect to be able to see, and why? What steps did you take to create the zip archive, or else where did it come from? What happens if you try using existing zip archive software to open the archive and check for these paths?

Are you sure the entries in the zip file contain paths?
Here is a zip file that contains a filename which has a path component.
$ unzip -l /tmp/text.zip
Archive:  /tmp/test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        4  2024-05-12 15:33   tmp/fred/data.json
---------                     -------
        4                     1 file

when I run namelist, like this
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/test.zip')

print (zip.namelist())

I get the output below, namely a filename with a path component.
['tmp/fred/data.json']


